# Issue with dom manipulation inside Directive link function - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I set up a directive as follows:

```
.directive('ogTakeATour', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '../scripts/directives/TakeATourTemplate.html',
    scope: {
     content: '@',
      uid: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      angular.element(scope.uid).css("top","250px");
    }
  };
 });
```

Directive template looks like this:

```
<div id="{{uid}}" class="tourContainer">
  {{content}}
</div>
```

And this is how I call my directive:

```
<og-take-a-tour content="Content goes here" uid="menuTour"></og-take-a-tour>
```

However for some reasons this does not apply the css to the applicable div.

```
angular.element(scope.uid).css("top","250px");
```

Why is this? Could it be that the directive does not know what the id of my element is at the time the link function is running? How would I get around this if that is the case?

Comment: What is `menuTour`? It's an `id` of some element or element itself?

Comment: I take menuTour which was defined as an attr in directive scope (uid: '@') and then add it as the div id in my directive template. I then take that id in my link function to add my css style

Answer (score 0):

Angular's jQlite does not support search by id or CSS selector. So change your code like this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + scope.uid)).css("top", "250px");
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. But what does work is if I do this -angular.element('.tourContainer').css("top","250px"); - which proves that you can search by class for jQlite however I need to be able to apply different styles for multiple instrances of the same directive

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the answer, can you please re-try to updated answer.

Comment: I see a problem with the directive. Can you please log the value of `scope.uid` in the directive and see what is the output

Comment: I logged scope.uid and did get - menuTour

Comment: Okay, can you open the browser console and run this `angular.element(document.querySelector('#menuTour')).css("top", "250px");` And see if your style is being applied or not